# Adding Firebase to JavaScript Project

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to programm a Chat Web-Application with Firebase. I am using HTML as a return method in Javascript. I tried to include my DB Firebase but I'm getting an error, that the DB is not defined. Can someone solve my Problem?

```
function Chats() {

  const username = prompt("What's your name?");

  document.getElementById("send-message").addEventListener("submit", postChat);

  function postChat(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const timestamp = Date.now();
      const chatTxt = document.getElementById("chat-txt");
      const message = chatTxt.value;
      chatTxt.value = "";
      db.ref("messages/" + timestamp).set({
        usr: username,
        msg: message,
      });
    }
  return (
      <div id="chat">

          <ul id = "messages"></ul>

              <form id="send-messages">

                  <input id="chat-txt" type= "text"></input>
                  <button id="chat-btn">Submit</button>
              </form>

              <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
              <script src="https://united-parents-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"></script>

      </div>
  );    
}
```

Comment: Hello, yes I am using React. thank you for your recommendation :)

Answer (score 0):

declare DB variable at start of your script

```
var db = firebase.database();
```

first you have to initialize the firebase

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
<script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "api_key",
        authDomain: "authDomain",
        databaseURL: "databaseURL",
        projectId: "projectId",
        storageBucket: "storageBucket",
        messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
        appId: "appId"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

you can get this from firebase console as well